# Error 'expected string or bytes-like object' in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a new record in my Django model but I just can't. Here is the Sell class model:

```
class Sell(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Buy, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sell', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the code in my view.py:

```
    Sell.objects.create(item=item,
                        date=timezone.now,
                        discount=Decimal(0.00),
                        total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
                        buyer=request.user, )
```

If I print all of this variables, the result is:

```
    print(item)
    266
    print(type(item))
    <class 'dma.models.Buy'>
    
    print(timezone.now)
    <function datetime.date at 0x03D3F460>
    print(type(timezone.now))
    <class 'function'>
    
    print(type(Decimal(0.00)))
    <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
    
    print(cart.get_total_price())
    68.00
    print(type(cart.get_total_price()))
    <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
    
    print(request.user)
    Felipe
    print(type(request.user))
    <class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>
```

Error:

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
expected string or bytes-like object

[image]

Comment: The code in your image is not the same as in your question.

Comment: @AKX It is the same he just reordered it , Like the create function he put it before the print statements on SO but in his code it came last .

Comment: @RaoufM No, it's not. The traceback shows `date=datetime.date`, the pasted code doesn't.

Comment: Guys, thank you! The code is now working. I should've made some mistaken and the initial code:          Sell.objects.create(item=item,
                                date=timezone.now(),
                                discount=Decimal(0.00),
                                total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
                                buyer=request.user, ) is now running properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *evaluate* the **`timezone.now`** by calling the function,

```
date=timezone.now()
```

```
Sell.objects.create(item=item,
              date=timezone.now(),
              discount=Decimal(0.00),
              total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
              buyer=request.user, )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know exactly what happened but the code is now working properly without this 'timezone.now' evaluate. Btw, why this evaluation is necessary?

Comment: `timezone.now` is the function and `timezone.now()` is the result of the fucntion

Comment: In this case I'm not evaluating and the code seems to work correctly with only this lines:             Sell.objects.create(item=item,
                                date=timezone.now(),
                                discount=Decimal(0.00),
                                total_paid=cart.get_total_price(),
                                buyer=request.user, ). Is it everything OK if I not add the first line 'date=timezone.now()'?